# Updating the path within a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, pip, activepython

I am writing a script that installs active python, and then "pip installs" two libraries:

```
IF %ARCH%==%tb% msiexec.exe /i Python\ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi /qb
pip install requests
pip install pyserial
```

When I run this I get: `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, ...`

But if I pull up powershell after the program is finished, pip has been added to my path and the listed commands work.

So my question is: How can I update the path within my batch file so I can use pip without starting a new process?

Comment: What is the `PATH` to pip?

Comment: @Endoro C:\Python27\Scripts\pip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
set "path=%path%;C:\my path update"
```

The semi colon is significant.